# converting an if statement to a conditional operator in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

How do I simplify this code with a conditional operator in Java?
This is from dr. Liang's Introduction to Java.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 3;
        int j = 4;
        int k = max(i, j);
        System.out.println("The max int is " + k);
    }

    public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
        int result;

        if (num1 > num2) {
            result = num1;
        }

        else {
            result = num2;
        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn things into a one-liner using the conditinal ternary operator:

```
return (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;
```

But just for the record: it would be better to keep that **max** method around; simply for the sake of readability. It *helps* to have that functionality in its own method.

But of course: you want to read about [java.lang.Math.max()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)) which already provides exactly **that** functionality (not only for *int*, but all the other numerical primitive types as well)!

So, the real answer is: yes, use a method for that check; but don't create your own version; use the one that is already coming with Java by default. In other words: do **not** re-invent the wheel. Even when it is just a small wheel like this one.

Comment: Sure, learning is always "different", but I guess you also learned that one theme "do not re-invent the wheel" today.

Comment: Sure, good point. Then lets reword that: one should know about existing wheels; and make a **conscious** decision about re-using existing wheels, or creating new ones. Both choices come with different (dis)advantages that should be taken into account when making decisions in the real world.

Comment: Whereas in IT, we have have far too many people that build their own wheels; very often ending up very much deficient compared to those that would be already available to us.

Comment: You are very welcome. I used IT to express the fact that yes, there is a **broad** spectrum of people creating software; and in the real world, and on stackoverflow, you are dealing with all kinds of people. Great discussion; have a good night. And for the record: I am already in bed, and I better shutdown my laptop now, too.

Answer (score 4):

While you could use the conditional operator `? :` to implement this

```
public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
}
```

But, I would *prefer* [`Math.max(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-) like

```
public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
    return Math.max(num1, num2);
}
```

You might also choose to use [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) and support an arbitrary number of `int`(s). Using an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) you could do

```
public static int max(int... nums) {
    return IntStream.of(nums).max().getAsInt();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand Math.max would be a better choice, of course. That is just for learning purposes (it was on the chapter book's on methods).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *conditional ternary operator*.

```
int k = (i > j) ? i : j;
```

This expression evaluates to:

If **i** is greather than **j**, assign **i** to **k**. If not, assign **j** to **k**.

Answer (score 2):

This would be one way to modify your example to use the ternary operator.

You should generally keep the values in the operator short otherwise they get hard to read.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 3;
        int j = 4;
        int k = max(i, j);
        System.out.println("The max int is " + k);
    }

    public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
        int result;

        result = (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;
        return result;

    }
}
```